# functions in c programming

Tags: c, function

I am new to c ,while i am writing a basic program in c ,it is showing two answers ..1)when i declare and intialize variables separately 2)when I declare and initialize variable in a same line.can any one tell me my mistake please?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
void sum()
{
    printf("enter the numbers to be added\n");
    int x=scanf("%d",&x);
    int y=scanf("%d",&y);
    int sum=(x+y);
    printf("the sum of two numbers is %d\n",sum);

}
int main()
{
    printf("welcome to addition calculator\n");
    sum();
    return 0;
}
```

I am getting 2 as answer when i gave 3 and 4 as inputs

Comment: Whenever you have a question about "Why is this C function doing something strange?" make sure you check the [scanf(3) - Linux manual page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/scanf.3.html) or the MS Docs equivalent for your implementation. The [C11 Standard](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html) is also a good reference.

Answer (score 1):

`scanf("%d", &x)` will store the read number into `x`. It will return the number of successfully read fields (`1` in your case). If you assign that return value to `x` afterwards, you overwrite whatever the user entered with that `1`. And `1 + 1` produce `2`.

Solution:

```
int x;
int y;
scanf("%d",&x);
scanf("%d",&y);
```

As David reminds in comments, you might want to check that all fields were read successfully. For example, in your case, if you enter a non-digit, `scanf` will not resolve the `%d` field as successful, and will return `0`. You can test this result to make sure the user did what they were supposed to do:

```
int x;
int y;
while (scanf("%d", &x) != 1) {
  printf("Enter a NUMBER, you illiterate buffoon!\n");
}
while (scanf("%d", &y) != 1) {
  printf("Enter a NUMBER! You managed with %d, how is this suddenly hard now?!\n", x);
}
```

Comment: Preferably with `if (scanf ("%d", &x) != 1) { /* handle error */ return; }` and the same for `y` -- just to make sure the OP knows that all input must be *validated*.

Answer (score 0):

scanf() function returns 1 if it scan successfully otherwise it return 0. That's why when you put an integer to x, scanf() return 1 and assign it to x(x=1). Same for y(y=1).

As x=1 and y=1. 
sum = 2